# UIButton doesn't respond to touches

Tags: ios, uibutton

In my app, I need to parse some data from the network, and add some customized buttons.
Later, when user click on it, I would provide more details.

- An image view is the background for the app
- The position of these buttons(xPos, yPos) are parsed from the server(dynamic data)
- no prints when I click on these buttons that I add programmatically

The code I have for adding it is like this

```
    ...
    [businessButton setImage:businessImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [businessButton setFrame:CGRectMake([xPos floatValue], [yPos floatValue], [businessImage size].width/2, [businessImage size].width/2)];
    [businessButton addTarget:self.imageView action:@selector(serviceProviderSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ...

- (void)serviceProviderSelected:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sp tapped\n");
}
```

I created another dummy app to do (what I think is the same thing), and the button works out fine...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIButton *customizedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"business-icon.png"];
    [customizedButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customizedButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 20, 20)];
    [customizedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:customizedButton];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"yes, pressed\n");
}
```

I've been suspecting that the buttons I create in code are already released, and printed out the array that I use for storing these Buttons, they are valid addresses though...

Thanks!

William

Answer (score 1):

I just found out why.

Instead of `[self.imageView addSubview:businessButton];`, `[self.view addSubview:businessButton];` works now.

I think I didn't really understand how the view relationship was after adding an imageView in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView has user interactions disabled by default. you have to set this property to YES in order to get an UIButton or anything else working as it's subview

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
[businessButton addTarget:self action:@selector(serviceProviderSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The target needs to be the class that defines the selector.

Comment: Thanks, BlackRider! I changed it, but still the same.

Comment: Also, make sure no other view (e.g. your image) is overlapping your button. If it is, it may eat the user input, unless you set its `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO.

Comment: You can make sure your button is on the top by doing something like `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:businessButton]`;

Comment: Thanks, BlackRider! I mistakenly used self.imageView addSubview, instead of self.view

Comment: btw, @BlackRider, how do I disable all controls covered by my view after this? Say, I have another button covered by the view I brought to top. My view is transparent, and I can see click the button.

Comment: Like I said, set userInteractionEnabled to NO for all the views that shouldn't receive the events, and YES, to those that should. Also, keep in mind that setting a view's alpha to 0 will cause it not to receive touches. Instead, you'll want to set alpha to 1, and backgroundColor to transparent.